# IOS Checking Active internet connection even connected via WIFI without internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

Please help me out how to check internet connection in iPhone.

I tried by checking the Apple's reachability framework, but it is not returning if connected via WIFI without internet.

What I am getting is reachable via wifi.

The other option I tried is making a synchronous request with google.com etc and checking the response code.

Is there any other way to check so that I can avoid making a url request and checking the response code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as i know you have to use "making a synchronous request with google.com", i had same issue if you got any other solution please share with me

Answer (score 1):

Check if wifi reachable (using Apple's reachability), and then make request to ensure host is reachable.

```
// wifi checking code here
//...
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourServer.com/someLightFile.html"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error) {
        // Your host is reachable
    }
}] resume];
```